# Angular2 with a table and a custom element on it

Tags: html, typescript, angular

I'm trying to make a table with angularJs2 `2.0.0-beta.0`. This table lists items. I would decouple the item from the list.

I have this code:
`app.item.list.html`

```html
<table class="table table-condensed"  [hidden]="items?.length==0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th >id</th>
      <th >col 2</th>
      <th >col 3</th>
      <th >col 4</th>
      <th >col 5</th>
      <th >col 6</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr *ngFor="#item of items" >
      <item-detail [item]="item"></item-detail>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The `app.item.list.ts`

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, Output, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChange} from 'angular2/core';
import {FORM_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/common';
import {Item} from './model/model.item';

@Component({
    selector: 'item-list',
    templateUrl: 'app/app.item.list.html',
    directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES, Item]
})
export class ItemList{

   @Input() Items:Array<Item> = new Array();
   public item: Item;

}
```

the `app.item.html`

```html
<td >{{item.id}}</td>
<td >{{item.col1}}</td>
<td >{{item.col2}}</td>
<td >{{item.col3}}</td>
<td >{{item.col4}}</td>
<td >{{item.col5}}</td>
```

And the `app.item.ts`

```
import {Component, Input, EventEmitter, Output, OnChanges, SimpleChange} from 'angular2/core';
import {FORM_DIRECTIVES, NgFor} from 'angular2/common';

@Component({
    selector: 'item-detail',
    templateUrl: 'app/app.item.html',
    directives: [ FORM_DIRECTIVES, NgFor]
})

export class Item{

  @Input() item:Item;

}
```

The Items informations are all displayed, but there is a format problem. All my items are raggrouped under the first column of the header (the id column).

[image: This is the result I get]

But I want to have the item.id under the id header, the item.col1 under col1 ....

What can I do having the list and the item decoupled?

P.S.: When they were in a single html and ts file, it worked well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I recived an answer on Github, and I post the solution here:
I have to change `app.item.list.html`

and `app.item.ts`

```
@Component({
    selector: '[item-detail]',
    ...
 })
 export class Item{
     @Input('item-detail') item:Item;
 }
```